# How to pass integer from an object instead of using toString() method?

Tags: java, tostring

I have the following object "Subject" that I am using to create a timetable. Now I know how to use the toString() method but i have to pass integer. It passes the value but i cannot get it to be shown properly

```
public String name;
public int Students;
public String NameOfLecturer;
public ClassVenu addVenues;
public int EncodedValue; 
public int NumberofLect;
public int NumberofLabs;
public String Type;


public Subject(String argName, String argNameofLecturer, 
    int argstudents, int argEncodedValue, ClassVenu argAddvenue, 
    int ArgLect, int ArgLabs) { 

    name = argName;
    NameOfLecturer=argNameofLecturer;
    students=argstudents;
    EncodedValue=argEncodedValue;
    addVenues=argAddvenue;
    NumberofLabs=ArgLabs;
    NumberofLect=ArgLect;

}


public String toString() { return "" + EncodedValue+ "";}
```

after that when i create an object for example :

```
Subject D = new Subject("Human Computer Interaction", "Batman" , 20,1111,null,1,3);
```

if i use the `toString()` my timetable would look like :

`[1001 , 1001 , 0 , 1010 .....]` *these are encoded

Is there anyway to replace toString method with something else that passes integer whenever I use subject?

Comment: You can make another method `display` but it will not work if you print any `list` because printing collections uses `toString` method

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... here is the deal , when i try to use integer, it shows something like   fyp_small_timetable.Subject@659e0bfd   instead of the actual integer. Is it just the matter of display ? Can I just simply ignore the display  part and pass on to other calculations using that ?

Comment: Are you sure `Subject` contains the `toString` you describe? The `@659e0bfd` is from `Object.toString()`.

Comment: it has the toString() method and it works perfectly fine. but I have to pass bunch of randomly generated timetables to Genetic algorithm. So i need my timetables to be list of integers not Strings. When I try to return "EncodedValue" as an integer I get it displayed as fyp_small_timetable.Subject@659e0bfd . not really sure if it's just the matter of display or I would face troubles passing it to GA.

Comment: if you don't **override** `toString()` then you will get reference Subject@659e0bfd .. If you want to display `Encoded Value` then you have to override it

Comment: How to override toString to pass integer?

Comment: I think I didn't get your problem right

Comment: Field names should start with lowercase.  The names of constructor parameters should match the fields they are assigned to.

Comment: For the purposes of getting an effective answer I recommend posting an SSCCE. http://sscce.org/

Comment: **toString()** cannot return **int** or **Integer** because it would conflict with the type of **Object.toString()** and not compile.

Comment: I knew that much ... that's why I am asking if there is anyway to use another method to replace toString so that I can return integer.

Comment: @HiradGorgoroth I have answered your question.  Please accept my answer.

Comment: I accepted sir , but unfortunately it did not work for me ... maybe have to check a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int getEncodedValue() {
    return EncodedValue;
}
```

Add the method above to your Subject class.  You can then call it to get your encoded values as `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you want to turn a String into an int, try this:

```
Integer.parseInt("100");
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible for me to do it in the easy way. I have somewhere around 200 randomly generated timetables which include many subjects. I wouldnt be able to do it one by one

Comment: @HiradGorgoroth can't you just parse them all in a loop?

Comment: It would be a very long loop that it has to go through millions of times... not really sure if it's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt(your_string_goes_here);`